# android crash even on "empty" activity

Tags: android, android-intent

I am having some trouble crossing between activities with Intent. I am using an intent to get to a new page, but my app is crashing.

Here is my code:

```
package il.co.erm.green;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class Setting extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_setting);
    }


}


    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="il.co.erm.green.Setting" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="pow" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

the application always crashes when I to click on the button to go to the new activity.

Here is the code for the button:

```
Button btnSettings = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Btn_settings);
    btnSettings.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
             Log.w("gilad", "kak");
            Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(),  Setting.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 0);

        }
    });
```

What could be the problem?

EDIT :
My logcat file:

```
11-16 13:12:45.164: E/AndroidRuntime(23102): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-16 13:12:45.164: E/AndroidRuntime(23102): Process: il.co.erm.green, PID: 23102
11-16 13:12:45.164: E/AndroidRuntime(23102): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {il.co.erm.green/il.co.erm.green.Setting}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
11-16 13:12:45.164: E/AndroidRuntime(23102):    at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1634)
11-16 13:12:45.164: E/AndroidRuntime(23102):    at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1430)
11-16 13:12:45.164: E/AndroidRuntime(23102):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3457)
11-16 13:12:45.164: E/AndroidRuntime(23102):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3418)
11-16 13:12:45.164: E/AndroidRuntime(23102):    at il.co.erm.green.DeviceControlActivity$7.onClick(DeviceControlActivity.java:323)
11-16 13:12:45.164: E/AndroidRuntime(23102):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4463)
11-16 13:12:45.164: E/AndroidRuntime(23102):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18770)
11-16 13:12:45.164: E/AndroidRuntime(23102):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
11-16 13:12:45.164: E/AndroidRuntime(23102):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
11-16 13:12:45.164: E/AndroidRuntime(23102):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
11-16 13:12:45.164: E/AndroidRuntime(23102):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292)
11-16 13:12:45.164: E/AndroidRuntime(23102):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-16 13:12:45.164: E/AndroidRuntime(23102):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
11-16 13:12:45.164: E/AndroidRuntime(23102):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824)
11-16 13:12:45.164: E/AndroidRuntime(23102):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640)
11-16 13:12:45.164: E/AndroidRuntime(23102):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

My manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="il.co.erm.green"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="19"
        android:targetSdkVersion="20" />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth_le"
        android:required="true" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/red_die"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".DeviceScanActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".DeviceControlActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".History"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_history" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Help"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_help" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Trip"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_trip" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Settings"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_settings" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".SettingsNew"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_settings_new" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".SettingsNewNew"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_settings_new_new" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Setting"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_setting" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Note: don't use 0, use `Activity.RESULT_FIRST_USER + n` where `0 <= n` is an arbitrary number you assign for your activities which have results. (this shouldn't solve your issue, just prevent future problems)

Answer (score 1):

I guess you forgot to add Setting Activity into your manifest.xml

```
<activity
            android:name="il.co.erm.green.Setting"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_setting">
</activity>
```

Comment: actually i do have it in the menifest, and yet it doesnt help :(

Comment: copy your logcat for more help.

Comment: see my update and add that snippet to your manifest's application tag

Answer (score 0):

Well , it seems like I had some other class in the way, which interfear with the code.